# ASP.NET NotInheritable Class with shared attribute

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i'm trying to build a NotInheritable Class with shared string. I need to use these string in my entire web application.

This is my class:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ParamNames

    Public Shared MODELLO_DA_CERCARE_PARAM = "mdc"

End Class
```

Now i'm trying to use this string in an handler in this way:

```
Dim modelloParamName = ParamNames.MODELLO_DA_CERCARE_PARAM
```

I don't have problem at compile time, but when i launch the application i get an error about  the protection level of ParamNames.

Help?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'ParamNames' is not declared. It may not be accessible because of its level of protection.

Comment: You might need to specify the namespace.

Comment: i've added <%@ Import Namespace="Methodo_app" %> in my .aspx pages and Imports Methodo_app in my .vb pages

Comment: What was the solution?  I'm having a similar problem where I can't use Public NotInheritable Classes in my App_Code folder.

Comment: Hi, i seen my vb code pages had in the "propertis" the attribute "Build Action" se to "Content". I've changed it to "Compile" and all worked. Hope this can help you